# insert a comma(',') between a list of numbers (each on new line) retaining new lines as well

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

i have a block of text like this

```
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890
```

i want to convert it to this

```
123
,234
,345
,456
,567
,678
,789
,890
```

how do i achieve this with regex replace in sublime text 3

i am currently replacing `'\n'` with `'\n,'` manually for every line

edit:
my complete file is something like this

```
xyz

123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890

abc
```

Comment: Can't you just use `Replace All` in the `Find` functionality? Find `\n` and replace with `\n,` worked fine for me with your current sample data.

Comment: Do you want only a section of numbers or just any line? Search: `^` replace: `,` should work to put a comma at the start of any line. Perhaps you can limit the replacement  to just the current selection, if you don't want to format the whole file.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to insert  a comma at the beginning of each line but the first? Do you really need to check if the lines in between are all digits? What do your input files look like in fact?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my input file looks something like 
`xyz
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890

xyz`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
^\d+\R\K(?=\d+$)
```

Replace with `,`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/879NDr/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `(?=\d+$)` - a line that only contains one or more digits should follow immediately to the right of the current position.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
^(?!\A)
```

- `^` Start of line
- `(?!\A)` Negative lookahead, assert not start of the string

And replace with `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GndTt6/1)